# how deos CallContext in Owin / Vnext work

Tags: owin

I have seen that in vnext that CallContext is used HttpContextAccessor and I tried to use same idea for a small owin dependency tracker but failed.

my middleware is setup like this:

```
        app.Use(async (ctx,next) =>
        {
            CallContext.LogicalSetData("BLABLABAL", new ObjectHandle(new request()));
            await next();
        });
```

and combined with application insight telemetry initializer:

```
public class ItemCorrelationTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public ItemCorrelationTelemetryInitializer()
    {

    }
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        //telemetry is a dependencyTelemetry
        var handle = CallContext.LogicalGetData("BLABLABAL") as ObjectHandle;
        var test = handle != null ? handle.Unwrap() as request : null;
        if(test != null)
            telemetry.Context.Operation.Id = test.test;
    }
}
```

but my problem is that the handle is always null;

So my question is that with vnext or owin without system.web, how can a dependency tracking module be made when the callcontext cannot carrie over the object as shown above.

Comment: Assuming that `Initialize` is (eventually) called by `next`, this should work. Can you put together a minimal repro?

Comment: @pksorensen - I filed the issue on Katana project: https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/workitem/440 Vote for it.

Comment: It seems it has to do with OWIN stage markers. The context will be correctly passed if the Controller is executed at the same stage as the middleware that called CallContext.LogicalSetData. Riana